# Calculate new value on UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

```
// open csv 
$handle = fopen("update.csv", "r");

// select cols
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
$model = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[0]);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[5]);
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[7]);
mysql_select_db("verradt33_develop", $link);

// replace comma with period and text with numbers
$price = str_replace(",", ".", $price);
$quantity = str_replace("JA", "10", $quantity);
$quantity = str_replace("NEE", "0", $quantity);

// execute
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE dev_product SET price='$price' , quantity='$quantity'     WHERE model='$model'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Above code works. Now I would like to know if it is possible to calcute `$price` to exclude VAT (21%) price.

Example:

CSV gives `1.99`. But I want `1.6446` to be inserted in the database.
(Which is `1.99 / 121 x 100` to exclude the VAT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `/1.21`

```
UPDATE dev_product 
SET price = $price / 1.21, 
    quantity = $quantity 
WHERE model = '$model'
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying it but the server and database stopped responding for some reason after running the changed script.